# My function keeps skipping the negative values from the list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

My function keeps skipping the negative values from the list of integers that I am reading from ratings(2).txt. I have tried multiple methods but it just doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
with open("ratings (2).txt", 'r') as old_ratings:
        my_list = []
        for line in old_ratings:
            temporary = line.split(' ')
            firstele = (line[2])
            try:
                int(firstele[0])
                my_list.append(firstele)
            except:
                pass
        for lst in my_list:
            for l in lst:
                    if l == '\n' or l == '0\n':
                        lst.remove(l)
        print(my_list)
```

Comment: What is your minimal input and expected output?

Comment: You never use the `temporary` var. Did you mean `firstele = (temporary[2])`?

Comment: You know that `int(firstele[0])` doesn't do an in-place conversion, right?  `firstele[0]` is still a string.

Answer (score 0):

Silently discarding exceptions makes things very hard to debug:

```
            try:
                int(firstele[0])
                my_list.append(firstele)
            except:
                # something failed, but now we'll never know why!
                pass
```

If you remove this `try/except` then the program will halt when it encounters a value it can't parse, and it will tell you what it is so you can figure out how to fix the problem.

If you don't want the entire program to halt when this happens, you can at least have it print out the exception by doing something like:

```
            try:
                int(firstele[0])
                my_list.append(firstele)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

I suspect what's happening is that you're trying to parse a string like `"-"` as an int.

Comment: Yes,  the error I get is: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'